# Sci-fi book where Earth collides with a planet from another universe and a piece of Earth is taken by it

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read this sci-fi book some 30 years ago (but it was older than that by maybe ten years?).

The Earth collides with a planet, possibly from another universe. A piece of Earth is taken by it with the people on it. With limited resources they start exploring and discover a primitive and strange world with stuff like fast gelatinous masses which can dissolve entire human bodies. After killing one it becomes wood-like and they cut it with axes to discover only the ring of a previously "eaten" human.

The humans get old-Earth tech to work again (radio communications, planes...) and rebuild civilization on this new, alien planet.

Comment: It Sounds like the type of story written in the 40s/50s. So I suspect the poster DID mean what he wrote, when he said "read it 30 years ago, but it might be 40 years older than that".

Comment: I have vague recollections of a story "Off on a comet"(?) by Jules Verne where a comet skims the earth and some people end up on it, struggling to survive. But I don't remember much else about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Francis Carsac, The Robinsons of the Cosmos

Comment: Welcome and thanks for your answer! Can you edit in some details as to why you think this answer fits the question? A summary or excerpt perhaps?

Comment: Could you [edit] this to explain how it matches the OP’s description? I.e. why is this the correct work?

Comment: From the goodreads summary: "A la suite d'une collision interplanétaire, un petit morceau de la Terre (exactement un petit morceau de la France) se détache de notre globe et se colle sur une planète inconnue"  So it matches on the origin part at least.  1955, so it's old enough.

Comment: Interestingly [ISFDb lists translations](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1038149) into Spanish, Portuguese, Romanian, Russian, Hungarian and Italian but _not_ English!

Comment: The settings she described point to Francis Carsac's book from 1955, titled The Robinsons of the Cosmos. I read the Hungarian translation of it.

Comment: "[the protagonist] n'aura aucun mal à se reconstituer une civilisation. Une voiture blindée, un cuirassé ou un champ d'exploitation de pétrole, ne semblent pas lui poser problème." So yes to rebuilding Earth technology too.

Comment: And yes to the horror story too. It's in it.

Comment: "I noticed, to the right, a huge light violet gelatinous mass, moving at a considerable speed [...] I looked back at the monster: its rich violet color was gone, turning to dull gray; it looked like a lichen-covered rock. [...] The monster, again violet, rushed upon him. [...] a dry noise resounded and a kind of spark reached the Canadian, who collapsed. He disappeared encompassed by the pseudopods. [...] the hard gelatin, which had become denser than wood, we found nothing but a gold ring!"

Comment: Full text of the book (in Portuguese, though google does a pretty good job): https://www.you-books.com/book/F-Carsac/Os-Robinsons-Do-Cosmos

Comment: Yes, that's the one, thank you, you made my day ! (I read it in Romanian as a teenager and I loved it)